# Ensuring that the main thread doesn't die before execution of all an asyncronous method

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have a function which needs to poll a certain server to obtain the status of a job I sent it. It is of the form:

```
public Foo PollForJobOutcomeAsync(int pollSpan, Action<Foo> callback)
{
    var caller = new AsyncMethodCaller((p, cb) =>
    {
        PollForJobOutcome(p);
        cb(this);
    });
    caller.BeginInvoke(pollSpan, callback, null, null);
    return this;
}

public void PollForJobOutcome(int pollSpan)
{
    while (job not completed)
    {
        DoSomething();//send request to server, change job status according to response
        Thread.Sleep(pollSpan);
    }
}
```

Now unfortunately if the main thread calling the `PollJobOutcomeAsync` method terminates before the method finishes execution I will not get the desired status update. How do I ensure that these functions finish execution before the main thread dies.

Comment: How does your main thread terminates? Winform or Console App?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Console app. But does it make a difference?

Comment: Just i need to know how your main thread terminates that's why asked, why can't you make main thread to wait for AsyncJob to finish?

Comment: If you mean using Thread.Sleep, then I can't because some times it may take anything between minutes to days to hours to complete. I know of no other way to make the main thread wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `WaitHandle` here.

```
IAsyncResult result = caller.BeginInvoke(pollSpan, callback, null, null);
```

`BeginInvoke` will return `IAsyncResult` pass this to your main thread by return value or somehow then from your main thread call

```
result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();//main thread waits here till Async Operation completes
```

Hope this helps